# Executing a batch class based on the class name or id entered in as a string or id

Tags: apex, batch, wrapper-class, dynamic-apex, actionpoller

I am creating a page in Salesforce that lists all our batch classes and will allow you to execute each one individually.

Basically I am querying every ApexClass, finding the batchable ones, and creating a wrapper for each batch class that contains a method to submit a batch as well as poll for job updates. The problem is I don't know how to initiate a class based on a string or id. This is how I normally submit batch jobs when I know the class name:

```
batchClass b = new batchClass();
id jobId = Database.executeBatch(b, 200);
```

The problem here is the class name is a string. Anyway I can execute a batch class without hardcoding the class name? Example class code:

```
public class batchtest1 {
    public batch[] batches {get;set;}

    public batchtest1() {
        createBatches();
    }

    public void createBatches() {
        batches = new list<batch>();
        string batchString = 'implements Database.batchable<sObject>';
        for (ApexClass ac : [SELECT id, Name, Body FROM ApexClass]) {
            if (ac.Body.containsIgnoreCase(batchString)) {
                batches.add(new batch(ac));
            }
        }
    }

    public class batch {
        public ApexClass batch {get;set;}
        public string batchSize {get;set;}
        public id jobId {get;set;}
        public AsyncApexJob job {get;set;}
        public boolean pollingActive {get;set;}

        public batch(ApexClass xbatch) {
            batch = xbatch;
        }

        // Runs when user presses "Submit" on a batch 
        public void submitBatch() {
            pollingActive = true;
            if (batchSize == null) {
                batchSize = '200';
            }
            // I want to dynamically execute a batch based on the class name (ApexClass.Name) or class id (ApexClass.id)
            // Example of how I normally do it when the class name is known:
            //      myClass b = new myClass();
            //      jobId = Database.executeBatch(b, integer.valueOf(batchSize)
            // In this case I usually know the class name (myClass), however I want this to be dynamic based off what classes come back in the query
        }

        // Called from the action poller to update job info
        public void updateBatch() {
            job = [SELECT id, ApexClassId, CreatedDate, CompletedDate, ExtendedStatus, JobItemsProcessed, NumberOfErrors, Status, TotalJobItems
                   FROM AsyncApexJob 
                   WHERE id = : jobId LIMIT 1];
            if (job != null) {
                if (job.CompletedDate != null) {
                    pollingActive = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And here is the example visualforce page code:

```
<apex:page controller="batchtest1">
<apex:form>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Dynamic Batches"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Available Jobs ({!batches.size})" id="pb1">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!batches}" var="b">
            <apex:column width="75px">
                <center><apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!b.submitBatch}" reRender="pb1" style="padding:2px 6px;"/></center>
                <apex:actionPoller rendered="{!b.pollingActive = true}" action="{!b.updateBatch}" reRender="pb1" interval="5"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Job Name" width="300px">
                {!b.batch.Name}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Batch Size">
                <apex:inputText value="{!b.batchSize}" style="width:50px;"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Status">
                <apex:outputText rendered="{!b.job = null}">
                    <span style="font-style:italic;color:red;">Not started</span>
                </apex:outputText>
                <apex:outputText rendered="{!b.job != null}">
                    {!b.job.Status}
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Started">
                <apex:outputField value="{!b.job.CreatedDate}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Completed">
                <apex:outputField value="{!b.job.CompletedDate}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you look at the `Type` class and specifically the `Type.forName(someStr)` method?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you create an instance of a class using Reflection pattern.

```
public Object createInstance(String clz) {
    Type typ = Type.forName(clz);
    Object instance = null;
    if (typ != null) {
        instance = typ.newInstance();
    }

    if (instance == null) {
        throw new BusinessException('Couldn\'t successfully instantiate an object for class ' + clz + '. Please check if Class name is correct, is compilable and current user has access.');
    }

    return instance;
}
```

You can pass return value of this method to `Database.executeBatch` as below:

```
Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<sObject>)createInstance('BatchClassName'), 200);
```

Comment: I am getting the error ' Invalid type: Batchable'. Please help.

Comment: I got it. Right way is : Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<sObject>)instance, 200);